# How to configure "react-i18next" with translation files in GatsbyJS. Always having missing key error

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I need to get translations from a Gatsbyjs project.
Reading all documentation, see that everybody uses react-i18next, but many diferent ways to configure, specially if you're running this over GatsbyJS.

I've tried everything, and always got a missing key error. What am I doing wrong?

First of all, I created a component, called i18n :

```
    import i18n from 'i18next';
    import { useEffect } from "react"
    import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
    import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend'; 

     i18n.use(Backend)
          .use(initReactI18next)
          .init({
            lng: 'en',
            fallbackLng: 'en',
            debug: true,
            resources: {
              "backend": { 
                loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
              }
            },
            interpolation: {
              escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
            },
            ns: ["brands"],
            defaultNS: 'brands',
            keySeparator:false,
            react: {
              wait: true,
            }
          })
  export default i18n;
```

Afterwards, I reuse this component in one of my pages

```
import i18n from '../../components/i18n'
    ...
const { t } = useTranslation();
    ...
{t("brands:NIKE")}
...
```

This is one translation file:

```
/src/locales/en/brands.json
```

The content of brands.json file is:

```
{ NIKE:"Nike" }
```

Despite all, I got the following error

```
i18next::translator: missingKey brands:NIKE
```

Comment: is the path is linked properly, i think the path is not linked properly so that's the reason its not able to find the key. Did you checked that one ?

Comment: If you mean, path : /locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json, is ok. It's located where has to be

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give {t("brands:NIKE")}, simply use {t("NIKE")} and also give lng attribute value to equal the translated file name  in i18n  file.